# how do I link a .rc (resource) file when compiling a win32 app with gcc through command line?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, gcc, resources

I have been following the forgers win32 tutorial, specifically [this](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/menus.html) section as of this moment, and was wondering how you would link the .rc(resource) file when compiling a win32 program? (I'm compiling through command line).

I was reading [this](http://fragglet.livejournal.com/4448.html) article which says you could do something like this `windres chocolate-doom-res.rc chocolate-doom-res.o` and compile this way`gcc other.o files.o etc.o chocolate-doom-res.o -o chocolate-doom.exe`

But when I tried doing `windres res.rc res.o` (res.rc is my resource file) it gives me this `windres: res.rc:3: syntax error`

res.rc

```
#include "resource.h"
IDR_MYMENU
BEGIN
    POPUP "&File"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "E&xit", ID_FILE_EXIT
    END

    POPUP "&Stuff"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "&Go", ID_STUFF_GO
        MENUITEM "G&o somewhere else",0,GRAYED
    END
END

IDI_MYICON ICON "menu_one.ico"
```

Any ideas?.

Comment: You just probably saved me hours of time! thank you for the article!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're missing the [MENU](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381025%28VS.85%29.aspx) resource type. You should write:

```
#include "resource.h"
IDR_MYMENU MENU
BEGIN
.
.
.
END
```

Comment: @sil3nt, no problem. That kind of thing happens, and your question is still useful.

Answer (score 7):

FFWD to 2020 Q4. In the era of `VS Code`, a lot of people are somewhat struggling with "beyond the basics" when trying to compile WIN32 GUI "Hello World" without Visual Studio. And yes, the resource file is probably the main stumbling block. That is a wider subject.

Since the question is only about how to "compile in" the rc file, let me answer only that.

Somehow you got to the point at which you also have `my_app.rc` and `resource.h`.

- to avoid some potential big hassle make sure you have `#include <windows.h>` at the top of the `rc` file
- resource compiler is called `rc`. If `cl.exe` is on the path, `rc.exe` is too.
- `rc` makes a binary `res` file from the `rc` file.
- `rc my_app.rc` will produce `my_app.res`

  - of course only if your rc file has no mistakes in there.
  - if `rc` can not find `windows.h` you can add the path to it like so
    `rc /i"C:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um" my_app.rc`
  - with your local path of course.
- to use the `res`, on the `cl` command line you need to pass the `res` file to the linker, like on this imaginary example cl compilation command line

```
cl /Zi /EHsc /Fe:my_app.exe my_app.cpp /link my_app.res
```

make sure `/link` is the last argument to your `cl` command line.

**EDIT**

Let's assume your project folder contains:

```
my_app.cpp
resource.h
my_app.rc
```

First, you will need to produce `my_app.res` as described above.
Second, in the VS Code  `.vscode/tasks.json`, you will have:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file",
            "command": "cl.exe",
            "args": [
                "/Zi",
                "/EHsc",
                "/Fe:",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "${file}",
                "/link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS ${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.res",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: cl.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

Notice the `/link` argument you need to add, to the otherwise standard tasks file generated by `VS Code`. Open `my_app.cpp` and perform `CTRL+SHIFT+B`. That will compile and link the active file into your WIN32 App, with your resources included.

Comment: Finally a concise and great explanation on how the resource files work.

Comment: Thanks @TCB13 . Understanding WIN32 resources this way might boost ones advantage considerably